# R: MySQL character encoding on Windows

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, mysql-workbench, dbplyr

I have problem with character encoding when pulling data from MySQL database that seems to be specific to Windows computer.

The easy solution that's working on the Linux computer:

```
# establish connection
db = src_mysql(user = "user", password = "pass", dbname = "training_db", host = "127.0.0.1", port = 3306)
# change/force the character encoding
dbGetQuery(db$con, 'SET NAMES utf8')
```

If I pull the table with this settings on Linux, everything looks fine, if I do it on Windows computer, I get messy variables from Czech characters in the database.

When I inspect the databases in MySQL Workbench on Win pc, everything seems to be allright.

Does anyone stumbled on the same problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in using dbConnect. Thus in this particular example:

```
db = dbConnect(drv = RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
username = "user",
password = "pass",
dbname = "training_db",
host = "127.0.0.1", 
port = 3306
)
```

Interestingly, I remember trying to use dbConnect on Linux, but after some issues gravitating to aforementioned src_mysql. Anyway, dbConnect is recommended even in the oficial guidelines nowadays [dplyr_guidelines](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/src_dbi.html) .